# rselenium | get the text of the webpage

Tags: r, phantomjs, plaintext, rselenium

Is there a way to get the plain Text from the remoteDriver in RSelenium?
Somethink like: `remDr$getPlainText()` as equivalent to `remDr$getPageSource()`.

**Workarount:**

I managed to save phantomJS's [plainText](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/plain-text.html) to a file as follows:

```
  require(RSelenium)
  pJS <- phantom()
  Sys.sleep(5) # give the binary a moment
  remDr = remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs')
  remDr$open()
  remDr$phantomExecute('var page = this;
                         var fs = require(\"fs\");
                       page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
                       var txtFile = fs.open(\"url.txt\", \"w\");
                       txtFile.write(page.plainText);
                       txtFile.close();
                       };')

  remDr$navigate(some_url)
```

But then i have to read the file in afterwords...

My workaround is done similar to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-headless.html#id3b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure whether if it solves the problem.

```
library(RSelenium)
checkForServer()
startServer()
re<-remoteDriver()
re$open()
re$navigate("link")
txt<-re$findElement(using='css selector',"body")$getElementText()
```

Comment: What? No, I just commrnted on the syntax itself :) `txt<-re$findElement` is not very readable, imho.